# Consume stdin multiple times in bash script

Tags: bash, tee

My script accepts a stream on stdin.  I want to pass the first line through to stdout no matter what, and grep the remaining lines with `-v` and also pass those out to stdout.

I worked out a solution using tee, but I'm wondering if this is guaranteed to always print the output of `head` before the output of `grep`?  What if `head` was replaced with something that blocked for 20 minutes before printing anything, would that output appear at the end of stdout after the output of `grep`?

```
tee >(head -n 1) >(tail -n +2 | grep -v -E "$PATTERN")
```

If the order is not guaranteed, what is the right way of doing this?

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: One more obvious problem with the two process substitutions is that although `head` only *outputs* one line, it's mostly likely reading blocks larger than one byte in order to find that first newline, and so will probably consume more than just the first line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are overthinking this and you don't need `tee`, `head` or `tail`.

You can consume the first line using `read` and just print it out, then use `grep` on the rest:

```
$ printf "foo\nbar\nquux\n" | { read v; echo "$v"; grep -v bar; }
foo
quux
```

Or, combining the logic into a single `awk` statement and avoiding the problem altogether:

```
$ printf "foo\nbar\nquux\n" | awk 'NR==1{print;next} !/bar/'
foo
quux
```

Answer (score 1):

You're right to be paranoid. The two sub-shells will run in parallel, so there's no guarantee that one will run before the other. To force an order of operations, read and print the first line before you grep the rest of the input.

```
read line && printf '%s\n' "$line"
tee >(grep -v -E "$PATTERN")
```

Comment: Cool yeah, that makes sense to use read in this case.  I guess I was curious about the solution to this in general (where I couldn't replace one of the two with read).

Answer (score 1):

I think I'd go for `sed`:

```
printf "Line1\nfoo\nbar\n" | sed '1n;/bar/d'
```

**Output:**

```
Line1
foo
```

That says... if it's line 1 print and go to next, else if the line contains `bar`, delete it.